# ArcGIS 10.4.1 ImportError: cannot import name multiarray with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, arcgis

I've installed ArcGIS 10.4.1, and with it the numpy 1.9.2 library. However, I get the following error when I try to run any scripts with numpy:

```
>>> import numpy
Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 
  170, in <module>
  from . import add_newdocs
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 
  13, in <module>
  from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py", 
  line 8, in <module>
  from .type_check import *
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\type_check.py", 
  line 11, in <module>
  import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", 
  line 6, in <module>
  from . import multiarray
  ImportError: cannot import name multiarray
```

I've tried uninstalling and re-installing ArcGIS, still with no luck.

Thanks in advance

Comment: you might have better luck as gis.stackexchange.com

Comment: Try removing `C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\lib\site-packages\numpy*` (note the wildcard, there might be another directory like `numpy-1.9.2.dist-info`) manually and then reinstall numpy (from within ArcGIS).

Comment: No dist-info directory in site-packages